# Type error:annot read properties of null (reading 'width')

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with the read properties, I don't know why this is throwing an error, earlier it was working fine, please see this
here is some code where it is  showing an error

```
      const ClarifaiFace=data.outputs[0].data.regions[0].region_info.bounding_box;
      const image = document.getElementById("inputimage");
      const width = Number (image.width);
      const height= Number (image.height);
       console.log(width, height);
       return {
         leftCol:ClarifaiFace.left_Col * width,
         topRow:ClarifaiFace.top_Row * height,
         rightCol: width - (ClarifaiFace.right_Col * width),
         bottomRow: height-(ClarifaiFace.bottom_Row * height)
         

       }
   };
```

Error:

> Type error:annot read properties of null (reading 'width')

Comment: Please provide more information. I would like to see the html associated with the image so we can see the id that you used and any initial styling. Also the code provided is incomplete it would be nice to at least see the code between the first and last brackets {} (i.e. the last } is unmatched).

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no such element with id `inputimage`. That's why `image` variable is `null` and therefore you are getting the error about reading property of null.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me when I got this error was changing "inputimage" to "inputImage" on getElementById in the 'image' variable. Hope this helps!

Comment: This will not make much difference the id must be whatever it is defined as on the image itself. However, you are right that camelCase is better practice for code readability.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).